# Easiest way for user to update slider and gallery images using Concrete5?

Tags: php, content-management-system, concrete5

To create an editable pane in C5 I use the following between div tags so the user can simply use the content editor to add text. This works quite well:

```
<div class="myWrapper">
<?php  
$a = new Area('WelcomeText');
$a->display($c);
?>
</div>
```

But what do I do when the mark-up is a little complicated? I would like to get user to update the 2 images and respective links themselves. Eg picture: http://i48.tinypic.com/4jma8p.png

What is the easiest way for non-code literate users to do this?

```
<ul class="Gal_2">
 <li class="Frst">
    <a href="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/Images/TEMP_IMG2.jpg" rel="group">
      <img src="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/Images/TEMP_IMG2.jpg" width="224" height="150" alt="Island Rab" align="left" />
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/Images/TEMP_IMG1.jpg" rel="group">
      <img src="<?php  echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/Images/TEMP_IMG1.jpg" width="224" height="150" alt="Island Rab - Lopar beach" align="right" />
    </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance...
PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom block with the free Designer Content addon: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/designer-content

The block you create will have two image fields that link to other pages, and then use "static html" fields to surround the images with your `<ul>` and `<li>` tags.

This is actually a perfect use case for Designer Content, so it should be fairly self-explanatory. But if you run into problems, post a message to the support forum (or just email me directly at concrete@jordanlev.com).